# Multiple duplicate dialog box on drag in IE11 when connected through VDI

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I am using the test code given below and facing issue with the javascript alert box (or any dialog box) in Internet explorer 11 in VDI. If the user drags or moves the alert box, it creates a duplicate of that box. Thus, doing so continuously opens multiple alert box. I am not facing this issue in IE8.

**Note:** I am facing this issue only while working on Client network connected through VDI. This issue is not reproducible when running it on eclipse in my local and using same IE11 version as on client network.

Is this issue related to network slowness. Please help me to fix this issue.

Login.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function validateForm() {
var x = document.forms["Login"]["fname"].value;
if (x == null || x == "") {
    alert("Name cannot be empty...");
    return false;
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="Login" action="AfterLogin.jsp"
onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

AfterLogin.jsp

```
<html>
<body>
<% 
String name=request.getParameter("fname");
if(name.equals("test"))
{
%>
<script>
alert("Login success...");
</script>
<%
}
else
{
%>
<script>
alert("Login fail...");
</script>
<%
}
%>
</body>
</html>
```

The duplicate alert box opens for "Login success..." and "Login fail..." alert box. If you continuosly drag this alert it will open mutiple alert box. This issue is not happenning for "Name cannot be empty..." alert box.

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Do not use `alert`, for god's sake!

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph: This is just a sample program to reproduce the issue...in our application we are different dialog boxes to show data validation messages to the user.

Comment: Don't show any messages to the user via `alert`, be it validation messages, debug or whatever. That dialog is a) modal; b) has nothing to do with design of your website (in case you have one at all).